# Set OpenCL device on OSX to dedicated AMD GPU

Tags: macos, opencl, torch, amd-gpu

I'm in the process of setting up Torch on OSX on a 2015 MacBook Pro with a Radeon GPU using [this library (cltorch)](https://github.com/hughperkins/cltorch/) for OpenCL support.

I can successfully run Torch scripts now, but running [this test script](https://github.com/hughperkins/cltorch/#custom-user-kernels) which outputs the device and platform being used I get:

```
Using Apple , OpenCL platform: Apple
Using OpenCL device: Iris Pro
```

Obviously, I want torch to run on Radeon instead of the integrated Iris, but I have no idea how to do that.

Comment: Having the same issue, ever manage to get this working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `cltorch.setDevice` to choose the device, like:

```
cltorch.setDevice(2)
```